# How do I make a bootable USB that deletes files?

Tags: windows, usb, bootable-media

I would like help on making a boot-able USB that would delete a .exe file in the D partition (Windows). How can I make this possible?

I have searched all over Google and still I found nothing.

Comment: Why not just use an Ubuntu Live CD? It should give you access to your NTFS drives to get rid files in question.

Comment: In addition to what Brutick suggested, why precisely are you trying to automate something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Linux LiveUSB and boot from that:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/